# Swift two question marks optional chaining

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I'm experimenting something with an optional chaining and two question marks but I can't understand one thing. I have this part of the code:

```
if let delegate = self.delegate {
    delegate.webViewControllerDidCancel()
}
else {  
    self.navigationController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

which is fine. Works exactly what I want to. If someone conforms to the protocol, call `webViewControllerDidCancel`, else simply `dismissViewController`.

However, I tried doing the same thing this way

```
self.delegate?.webViewControllerDidCancel() ?? self.navigationController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

which seems legit to me and also works, but XCode is giving me a yellow exclamation mark saying

> Result of call to '??' is unused

That I can't figure out. Is this ?? even supposed to work this way?

Comment: it does not seem legit if `–webViewControllerDidCancel` returns `void` or something else which is not evaluable.

Comment: yes, it's void. So that is probably the reason for the warning. Anyway, ended up using longer version, but I must say that this works too (not sure about the side effects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me that the `??` operator is designed for use in setting variables when working with optionals, and although it does seem to work as a mechanism to control which function to fire - that is not its directly intended use. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html):

> The nil coalescing operator is shorthand for the code below:

```
a != nil ? a! : b
```

> The nil coalescing operator provides a more elegant way to encapsulate this conditional checking and unwrapping in a concise and readable form.

All the examples on the documentation are variable related as well, so while the operator's functionality does fit your use case - Xcode's warning is related to you not using the operator for it's assumable intended use.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it's probably that the nil coalescing operator expects some assigning on the left and when it's used with functions, that doesn't happen.

Comment: Sure, I agree - the error message is very indicative of expecting you to do something with the result of the expression using the operator. I would assume very little side effects, if any, from using it as you have though.